# Lower Roman List with Parenthesis required

Tags: html, css

I need to generate output like this with the help of css...

(i) What is the demand?

(ii) For what segment(s)?

(iii) Given the innovative...

(iv) Given the innovative...

...and so on.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this with `counter-increment` property .write like this:

```
ul{
    counter-reset:item;
    list-style:none;
}
li:before        {
    content: "("counter(item, lower-roman) ")";
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/MEBxA/

It's work till IE8 & above.

Comment: The markup should be `ol` not `ul`, since `ol` gives better fallback (normally numbered list) than `ul` (bulleted list) for this case.

Comment: It's doesn't matter here because in this OP want's brackets also with the lower-roman & if he didn't want brackets with them then OL is great.

Comment: Huh? What do the parentheses have to do with whether you choose `ol` or `ul`?

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you want numbering that is in any way different from the numbering styles that can be achieved simply by using `list-style-type`, you have basically two options:

1. Suppress the default numbering with `list-style: none` and generate the numbers using counters, generated content, and `:before` pseudo-element (as in sandeep’s answer).
2. Include the numbers in the content, possible using server-side techniques to generate them. Either suppress the default numbering for `ul` or (somewhat safer) do not use `ul` markup at all but e.g. `div` elements or `table` markup.

The simplest example of the latter approach:

```
(i) What is the demand?<br>
(ii) For what segment(s)?<br>
…
```

In order to make it easy to style the rendering of the list as a whole, its items, and the numbers, it is better to use more verbose markup, perhaps up to this:

```
<div class=ol>
<div class=li><span class=num>(i)</span> What is the demand?</div>
<div class=li><span class=num>(ii)</span> For what segment(s)?</div>
…
</div>
```

(Using `blockquote` and not `div` as outermost markup would greatly improve the fallback, i.e. non-CSS rendering, but it would probably cause accusations of “semantically wrong” markup.)